# Python discord bot closes/crashes immediately after opening

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot with `discord.py` for my discord server, I have extremely basic code that should get the bot online but instead just opens and then crashes.

```py
import discord

@client.event
asnyc def on_ready():
    print 'bot read`enter code here`y'

client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

I do have the token normally I just didn't want to leak.  I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Run in in a way that allows you to get the error that it's crashing with. Run it in a console so it'll stay open, or in an IDE or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice [tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#how-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-python) to create a discord bot in python. Therefore you can create a connection with the following code:

```py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And I would suggest to rename the file from 'discord' to 'bot' or something else, so there are no conflicts with the import.